# Changing the background color of the grid in bootstrap including the sides it doesn't reach

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Sorry if this is worded poorly, so if I had something like this

```
<body>
<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">Some Text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">Some Text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">6</div>
</div>
</main>
</body>
```

I'd want to change the color of #test to something else but if I do something like

```
body {
   background-color: grey;
}
#test {
   background-color: yellow;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

It will only color the background of the grid and not the entire page. The sides of the page will remain white and I don't know how to remedy this

I'd like the yellow to reach the edge of the page

[Example of the yellow not reaching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyJYv.png)

Comment: Can you share the full code here or share a URL where we can check?

Comment: You mean this> body{
   background-color: grey;
}

Comment: Heres what happens when I do that https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyJYv.png It doesn't allow the yellow to reach the edge

Comment: Actually you'll have to use `.container-fluid` > `.row.bg-primary` > `.container` > `.row` > `.col`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the backgorung of the the page add css as

```
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

And for the background of the grid to be different take the grid `id` as `#test` and aplly the css as

```
#test {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

And channge your `main` class to

```
<main class = "container-fluid">
```

Have a look at the following image 
[image]

**Note:** `Body` changes the color of the whole body of the page whereas `#test` changes the color of the test id specified to respective class.

Comment: But the sides of the grid are still the body background color and not the color of the grid

Comment: can you please provide your whole code i wanna see the upper part of the code.

Comment: I changed it to my exact code, this is what it's giving me https://i.imgur.com/Cdd50Qf.png

Comment: Check out my edited code it will work.

Comment: It was because of the class container which leaves some margins to left and the right side .

Comment: Oh I see! Is there any special way to keep the class="container" look while expanding the background or will I have to change it and just mess the margins?

Comment: Actually these are the default classes created by bootstrap but if you have to name the class as `container` you must make changes in the bootstrap.css file for the class container.

Comment: Ok perfect, thank you!

Comment: if the user is using boottstrap itself that classes should have been used!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh ok.

Comment: @KunalRaut although giving it a thumbs up!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh thanks i was just solving the doubts before for classes and your statement is 100% correct about it though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
    #test
     {
     Background-color:grey;
     background-size:cover}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work, thanks for the help though

Comment: Change background-color to background-image